# How to cache a page on IIS and client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache

i  want to cache my page and use this type of caching

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 21600, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
          //some codes
        return View();
    }
```

but i 'm confused this type of cache will stored on IIS or on client browser?

how can i cache my page on user browser not on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default asp.net cache pages everywhere it can (server, proxy, client). You can change this by attribute

```
[Output(Location=OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
```

You can set the Location property to any one of the following values:

- OutputCacheLocation·Any
- OutputCacheLocation·Client
- OutputCacheLocation.Downstream
- OutputCacheLocation.Server
- OutputCacheLocation.None
- OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient